# Shap Summary Plot not displaying using XGB

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I am trying to display the summary plot but somehow it does not work. What works though is displaying a force plot. Why is the summary plot not showing?

```
import shap
shap.initjs()
model = XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model,data = X_train,model_output='probability') 
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, features=df_enc, feature_names=df_enc.columns,show=True)
```

It displays nothing when my force plot is showing data. What could be the issue?